How to add Metadata in Excel File Created with ReportViewer
In an application developed using ASP.NET Web Forms, I am creating reports with Microsoft ReportViewer and allowing users to download these reports in Excel format. However, I would like to control the metadata (title, author, keywords, etc.) that is included in the automatically generated Excel file.
The .NET version I am using is .NET Framework 4.6.1.
I am aware that I can solve this problem by creating a different export button, but I would like the metadata to be included in the Excel file created by the export button in ReportViewer.

I don't believe there is any support from such RDL reports. Hence, you can add/change the buttons on the web based formviewer, and you can run code to export the report to excel, and then you would have to add the meta data. Not at all ideal, but I'm not aware of any other approach.

To add metadata to an Excel file generated with ReportViewer, using C# code you will need to manipulate the document properties within Excel itself, after generation. ReportViewer itself does not have native support for adding metadata directly to exported files (such as author, title, or keywords) in Excel format.
However, you can follow these steps to add metadata:
1. Generate the Excel file with ReportViewer
Use ReportViewer to generate the report and export it as Excel, using the following code:


Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamIds;
string mimeType = string.Empty;
string encoding = string.Empty;
string extension = string.Empty;


byte[] bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render(
    "EXCEL", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension,
    out streamIds, out warnings);

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\output\report.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}



2. Add the metadata using the Open XML SDK library
To add metadata to the Excel file after it is created, you can use Microsoft's Open XML SDK library. With it, you can open the generated file and add the desired properties.
Install the Open XML SDK library via NuGet:


dotnet add package DocumentFormat.OpenXml --version 3.1.0



OR:
Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml

After installing, you can use the following code to add metadata:


using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.CustomProperties;
using System.IO;

public void AddMetadataToExcel(string filePath)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
    {
        var propertiesPart = document.PackageProperties;

        propertiesPart.Creator = "Author name";
        propertiesPart.Title = "Report Title";
        propertiesPart.Subject = "Report Subject";
        propertiesPart.Keywords = "keyword1, keyword2";
        propertiesPart.Description = "Excel file Description";
        propertiesPart.LastModifiedBy = "LastModifiedBy Name";
        propertiesPart.Revision = "1";
    }
}



3. Calling the method after generating the file
Once the Excel file is generated by ReportViewer, call the AddMetadataToExcel method:


AddMetadataToExcel(@"C:\output\report.xlsx");



Done!
